# Should the state in BLoC pattern be thread-safe?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm newbie to the BLoC design pattern, and I have a question about it:
Does `state` requires (green) thread-safety?

I give a short psuedocode below:

```
class Bloc {
  State state;
  
  StreamSubscription subscription;
  
  void subscribe(Stream src) {
    this.subscription = src.listen(this.businessLogic);
  }
  
  async void businessLogic(Object data) {
    State oldState = this.state;
    State newState = await someAsyncFunction(oldState); // <-- here
    this.state = newState;
  }
}
```

In this case, I guess a race condition may happen if two data successively arrive at `src`:
If the second data arrives while the first data is awaiting `someAsyncFunction`, the `oldState` will be the initial state for both of the first and second call of `businessLogic`.

Is there any good insight about this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dart by default runs on the only 1 thread, so there's no concept of threads in dart. The equivalent term is Isolates and Event Loops which manages Isolates which runs your code on separate thread. So, to answer your question "No", if you don't use Isolates BLOC don't require thread safety.

If you are using Future then It'll also use same Event loop and make your Future function wait till response arrives from the execution of that Future function, so if you want to wait till the response arrives and after that assign another value to newState then you need to use Async await in following fashion.

```
 Future<void> businessLogic(Object data) async{
    State oldState = this.state;
    State newState = await someAsyncFunction(oldState); // <-- here
    this.state = newState;
 }
```

More info on Isolates and Event loops [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vl_AaCgudcY).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know Dart defaults single-thread model, but the problem still exists (actually I mention it as "green thread safety") where this.state is read -> read -> update -> update -ed, instead read -> update -> read -> update. Is the code you gave resolve this problem?

Comment: @YukiHashimoto no it doesnot, but it's about the how threading works in dart.